# How to check whether a (generic) number type is an integral or nonintegral type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, math

I've got a generic type `T`. Using [Marc's `Operator` class](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) I can perform calculations on it.

Is it possible to detect by mere calculations whether the type is an [integral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6bf8dw1(v=VS.71).aspx) or a [nonintegral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6z3yf91(v=vs.71).aspx) type?

Perhaps there is a better solution? I'd prefer to support any possible type, so I'd like to prevent hard-coding which types are integral/nonintegral.

**Background info**

The situation I find myself in is I want to cast a `double` to `T` but round to the nearest value of `T` to the `double` value.

`int a = (int)2.6` results in `2` while I want it to result it in `3`, without knowing the type (in this case `int`). It could also be `double`, in which case I want the outcome to be `2.6`.

Comment: An integer is also a real number...

Comment: @StevenJeuris - No, a integer in C# HAS to be a real number, so what you want to figure out is not clear.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: But not all real numbers are integers.

Comment: @StevenJeuris - you want to know if a real number is an integer or not, right? I.e., whether it lacks a non-zero decimal component when represented in base 10. I assume you are *not* working with non-real numbers (i.e., numbers which have a factor of sqrt(-1)).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Updated the question one last time (hopefully). Removed any reference to math altogether. :) It is integral vs nonintegral I am looking for; don't know how to translate that to math.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: I'm not sure why you think that integral vs non-integral is not maths. Its certainly maths enough for me. :)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)? Something like:

```
Convert.ChangeType(1.9d, typeof (T))
```

It will work for all numeric types I think (as long as the first parameter is iConvertible and the type is a supported one which all basic numerics should be I believe).

Its important to mention that this will call something like double.ToInt32 which rounds values rather than truncates (bankers rounding I believe).

I tested this in a little LinqPad program and it does what I think you want:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = RetNum<decimal>();
    foo.Dump();
}

public static T RetNum<T>()
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(1.9d, typeof (T));
}
```

Comment: And here I was halfway through writing a generic method to do exactly what `ChangeType` does. +1.

Comment: I don't know whether I should accept this or not. :) It doesn't answer the question, but yes, it is a solution to the situation which made me ask this question. However, I bet it is pretty damn slow (compared to conditionally calling `Math.Round()`) and this can be called very often. It also relies on `IConvertible` being implemented, which is less of an issue. I'd prefer to check one time whether a type is integral or not, and conditionally call `Math.Round()` based on that cached result.

Comment: I would have thought the performance wasn't too bad to be honest. Mainly because it seems to do exactly what you want and I would assume that the .NET people have written it as efficiently as possible. Other ways I can see discussed in comments seem to be using more than just `Math.Round()` (eg I can see talk of Expression.Convert) so I'd be unsure of their performance as well. I'd suggest actually testing what I've suggested to see how it peforms. You may find that any alternative ends up with a lot of logic to deal with the edge cases, etc.

Comment: Also as a note I've just checked how Convert.ChangeType works and it does basically loop over all the possible types defined in iConvertible and calls the `ToX` method on whichever is appropriate. This should be pretty speedy I'd have thought.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method which will determine if a particular value stored in a generic numeric type is an integer without hardcoding. Tested working for me on .NET 4. Correctly handles all built in numeric types (as defined in the MSDN link at the bottom) except `BigInteger`, which doesn't implement `IConvertible`.

```
        public static bool? IsInteger<T>(T testNumber) where T : IConvertible
        {
            // returns null if T is non-numeric
            bool? isInt = null;
            try
            {
                isInt = testNumber.ToUInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == testNumber.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                // casting a negative int will cause this exception
                try
                {
                    isInt = testNumber.ToInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == testNumber.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // throw depending on desired behavior
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // throw depending on desired behavior
            }
            return isInt;
        }
```

Here's a method which will determine whether a particular type is an integral type.

```
    public static bool? IsIntegerType<T>() where T : IConvertible
    {
        bool? isInt = null;
        try
        {
            isInt = Math.Round((double)Convert.ChangeType((T)Convert.ChangeType(0.1d, typeof(T)),typeof(double)), 1) != .1d;
            // if you don't round it and T is float you'll get the wrong result
        }
        catch
        {   
            // T is a non numeric type, or something went wrong with the activator
        }
        return isInt;
    }
```

[`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) is the way to convert, with rounding, between two generic numeric types. But for kicks and curiosity, here's a way to convert a generic numeric type to an `int`, which could be extended to return a generic type without too much difficulty.

```
    public static int GetInt32<T>(T target) where T : IConvertible
    {
        bool? isInt = IsInteger<T>(target);
        if (isInt == null) throw new ArgumentException(); // put an appropriate message in
        else if (isInt == true)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = target.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return i;
            }
            catch
            {   // exceeded size of int32
                throw new OverflowException(); // put an appropriate message in
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                double d = target.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return (int)Math.Round(d);
            }
            catch
            {   // exceeded size of int32
                throw new OverflowException(); // put an appropriate message in
            }
        }
    }
```

My results:

```
        double d = 1.9;
        byte b = 1;
        sbyte sb = 1;
        float f = 2.0f;
        short s = 1;
        int i = -3;
        UInt16 ui = 44;
        ulong ul = ulong.MaxValue;
        bool? dd = IsInteger<double>(d); // false
        bool? dt = IsInteger<DateTime>(DateTime.Now); // null
        bool? db = IsInteger<byte>(b); // true
        bool? dsb = IsInteger<sbyte>(sb); // true
        bool? df = IsInteger<float>(f); // true
        bool? ds = IsInteger<short>(s); // true
        bool? di = IsInteger<int>(i); // true
        bool? dui = IsInteger<UInt16>(ui); // true
        bool? dul = IsInteger<ulong>(ul); // true
        int converted = GetInt32<double>(d); // coverted==2
        bool? isd = IsIntegerType<double>(); // false
        bool? isi = IsIntegerType<int>(); // true
```

Additionally, [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) has some example code which might be helpful. Specifically, it includes a list of types considered to be numeric.

Comment: Problem with this solution is you have to pass `testNumber`. I don't know the type, so I can't pass a sample value. I _can_ however cast a double value to the unknown type, but at that point the decimal part can already be lost if its an integral type.

Comment: Good point, I was only thinking in one direction. Also, my code detects whether the *value* is an integer, but you want to know whether the *type* is integral. Edit forthcoming.

Comment: Also figured of using `Activator.CreateInstance` at some point. But this will fail for custom types which don't have an empty constructor. :) P.s. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8526765/590790). Haven't gotten to implementing it yet, but believe I might be onto something, it might interest you as well.

Comment: Very true. The sticky point is that there doesn't seem to be a way to check whether a type is integral without at least one instance of that type. Going to investigate use of reflection to find appropriate constructors for custom types. The division in your answer is pretty slick!

Comment: Oh, totally skipped that `0.1d` part. I don't see why you need the `Activator` :/. `double` -> `T` -> `double` could work! That only leaves the question whether for some custom types other than `float` due to precision issues it would be rounded differently? +1 for all your effort on this!

Comment: Excellent point, amended the method. This is what happens when I have nothing to do at work. Missing obvious things like what you just suggested or the fact that `BigInteger` doesn't implement `IConvertible` is what happens when I get things to do at work and try to split my attention.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but:

To check if it's an integral **type**, use this: `if (obj is float || obj is double)`, or `if typeof(T) == typeof(float) || typeof(T) == typeof(double))`

To check if it's an integral **value**, cast it to a double, and then do `if(value == Math.Round(value))`

Of course, that is assuming that you have a number in the first place. I believe that the Operator class you're using supports things like DateTime. Would it be better to make your generic method have a generic constraint [`where T : IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)? That way there'd be explicit `ToDouble` and `ToInteger` methods.

**Edit**:

I think I understand: you've got two local variables, `double d; T num;`. You want to cast `d` to type `T`, but with proper rounding if `T` is a integral type. Is that correct?

Assuming that's correct, here's what I'd do:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>()
{
    double d;
    // I think I got all the floating-point types. There's only a few, so we can test for them explicitly.
    if(typeof(T) != typeof(double) && typeof(T) != typeof(float) && typeof(T) != typeof(Decimal))
    {
        d = Math.Round(d);
    }
    T converted = Convert.ChangeType(d, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Concerning `IConvertible`, not a bad idea at all. Am considering it now. Checking the type explicitly is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: ... however, that doesn't solve my actual issue which is mentioned in the example. ;p I need to check whether it is nonintegral so that I now whether or not I have to round the value.

Comment: So if the result is not a whole number, you want to round it to a whole number, is that it?

Comment: No, I only want to round it to a whole number if the type I am converting too is an integral type, not when it is e.g. a double.

Comment: Is this correct: You've got a double, and you want to convert it to a `T`, but with proper rounding if `T` is an integer type? See edit.

Comment: That is correct, but again I'd prefer not checking the type explicitly. Not checking for specific types would mean it's applicable even for custom types.

Comment: There are only so many built-in integer and floating point types. The built-in types, I think it's fine to enumerate and test for explicitly. If you want this to automatically handle numeric types that aren't built-in, I don't think there's a way to do it: There's no interface or property that means "this type supports decimals". Custom classes could be either floating point or integers, and there's just no way to know.

Answer (score 2):

[Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524356/590790) gives a possible solution to the scenario I mentioned, but for performance reasons I am still attempting to answer the actual question.

The *assumption* (untested) is, `Convert.ChangeType` is much slower than `Math.Round()`. Ideally, I can check one time whether the given type is integral or not, and conditionally call `Math.Round()` from then on to obtain a much more efficient solution than calling `Convert.ChangeType()` constantly.

I'm attempting the following implementation:

1. Convert both `3`, `2` and `1` to the desired unknown type. (This assumes a conversion from an `int` to the numeric type is possible, which should always be possible anyhow.)
2. In case `3 / 2 == 1`, it is an integral type. Otherwise, it is a nonintegral type.

This solution doesn't rely anywhere on knowing the type and solely uses conversions and calculations.

Comment: You can't assume implicit conversions with `int` for custom classes, and it's not defined for `BigInteger`.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: My mistake. It doesn't have to be implicit. I'm thinking of using [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) which also allows explicit. As far as assuming it is convertible, that's a requirement I'm willing to rely on. It makes sense for a numeric type to be convertible to at least an integral type.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I just realize, this has a similar _"problem"_ as in your solution. Suppose you make a custom type suited for a very precise range between 0 and 1. Conversions to 2 and 3 won't be possible.

Comment: That's why I've been comparing against 0.1. Assuming the conversion to double exists, your high precision custom type would be properly tested by my code. However, mine would fail for custom types that don't have a conversion to double. The other problem this method has is that it requires the division operator to be defined. Generally, I don't think it's possible to compare against a custom type. I can't get a comparison against `BigInteger` to work. You can't cast to it from primitive numerics. You can use a constructor, but that's no good, since it introduces more restrictive requirements.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: A type that doesn't define the division operator isn't a numeric type. For comparisons you can use `IComparable`, or just the comparison operators, which it should implement as well anyhow. Conversion to `double` is expected to be supported as well for a proper numeric type, _but_, what I meant with having a similar problem is that e.g. a fictional custom floating point with a precision of `.5` won't work with your solution. But all that is pretty fictional. :)

Comment: I prefer using my solution because I can throw an exception when the conversion from 1, 2 and 3 to `T`, and back to a double doesn't yield 1, 2 and 3. That's not possible with `.1`. :)

Comment: I agree it's not a numeric type without the operator, but the compiler has no way of ensuring that it's defined. You can't put `where T : defines operator/` on the check method's signature, so you can't compile a method that tries to divide instances of T. I spent time on IComparable as well, and you have to hardcode the types, because you have to cast your static value before doing the comparison. Point well taken about float precision, and our two approaches could be easily combined, but neither one can successfully check `BigInteger` without relying on constructor signatures.

Comment: Next week I'm continuing work on this and I'll write some unit tests to see whether it works for `BigInteger`. I don't see why I have to know about the constructor. P.s. I do check [at runtime whether operators are supported](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8523061/590790).