# How to verify whether a type overloads/supports a certain operator?

Tags: c#, reflection, operators

How can I check whether a certain type implements a certain operator?

```
struct CustomOperatorsClass
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }


    public CustomOperatorsClass( int value )
        : this()
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    static public CustomOperatorsClass operator +(
        CustomOperatorsClass a, CustomOperatorsClass b )
    {
        return new CustomOperatorsClass( a.Value + b.Value );
    }
}
```

Following two checks should return `true`:

```
typeof( CustomOperatorsClass ).HasOperator( Operator.Addition )
typeof( int ).HasOperator( Operator.Addition )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quick and dirty way to find out, and it works for both built-in and custom types. Its major drawback is that it relies on exceptions in a normal flow, but it gets the job done.

```
 static bool HasAdd<T>() {
    var c = Expression.Constant(default(T), typeof(T));
    try {
        Expression.Add(c, c); // Throws an exception if + is not defined
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Already considered that. This could actually still be the best solution, since this will continue working even when e.g. new built-in types are added as long as Expression Trees are supported. Don't know how much slower than reflection it would be, but a method like `HasOperator` isn't supposed to be called often anyhow.

Comment: looks like "exception driven programming", but I have to admit this is the best way to make a short,clean method to resolve the issue, including all operators, not just only addition.

Comment: Thought of a possible issue with this solution. What if you want to support reference types? `default(T)` would return `null`.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I verified that this snippet supports reference types as well, because the solution uses the `Expression.Constant(object,Type)` overload. Essentially, it creates `null` constant of the desired type.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Oh, of course. It doesn't matter whether or not it is null as it isn't meant to be executed.

Comment: @DannyChen: Exactly, this is the best answer, considering you want to support **any** operator. Otherwise you have to go through the mess of checking for built-in types, based on the operator you are looking for. (`&&` has to check for `bool` while `+` has to check for `int`, `short`, ...)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just for reference, it can also be done with `dynamic` - `try{object test = ((dynamic)a)+((dynamic)b);}catch(RuntimeBinderException ex){/*dosomething*/}`

Answer (score 7):

You should check if class have method with `op_Addition` name
You can find overloaded method names [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),
Hope this helps

Comment: Nice link! Do you know if you can pull the same trick on built-ins?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Once everything compiles I'll check whether that's possible. Otherwise I'll have to add additional logic to check for built-ins.

Comment: Honestly I don't know about built ins, leave comment after check please

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Unfortunately, `typeof(int).GetMethod("op_Addition")` returns `null`.

Comment: for reference: yup, just as `dasblinkenlight` pointed out, it currently doesn't cover built-in operators on built-in types - still, it's AFAIK the best solution *not relying on binding or exceptions*

Answer (score 4):

An extension method called `HasAdditionOp` like this:

```
pubilc static bool HasAdditionOp(this Type t)
{
    var op_add = t.GetMethod("op_Addition");
    return op_add != null && op_add.IsSpecialName;  
}
```

Note that `IsSpecialName` prevents a normal method with the name "op_Addition";

Comment: `bool` doesn't support addition. But +1 nonetheless for mentioning `IsSpecialname`.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Ya, I found the `bool` issue after posting this answer. And `string` doesn't implmenet the `-` operator. So it's really hard to tell all primitive types in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dynamic` keyword, which is only evaluated at runtime.

```
using System.Dynamic;

public static bool TryAdd<T>(T a, T b, out T result)
{
    dynamic _a = a, _b = b;

    try {
        result = (_a + _b);
        return true;
    } catch {}

    result = default;
    return false;
}
```

Note that this method also adds the two values together.

This could still be further optimised, as casting to type `dynamic` will perform boxing, and vice versa.